# What is the correct way to use pointer of pointer in a function?

Tags: c

I use a function that displays a block of memory's content pointed by a pointer.
But didn't get the desired output, i am new to this, please correct my if i am wrong.
when I input size =3, element = 1,2,3 , I got output = 1 only.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void merge(int **arr1);

int main(void) {
    int size1;
    printf("Give me the size of first array\n");
    scanf("%d", &size1);

    int *arr1 = malloc(size1*sizeof(int));
    int *p1=arr1;
    printf("Give me the elements of first array\n");
    int index1;
    for(index1 = 0 ; index1<size1; index1++)
    scanf("%d", p1++);

    merge(&arr1);
    return;
}

void merge(int **arr1) {
    while(**arr1)  //**arr1 is the content of the passed array, if there 
                  // is an int in it, print that out and increment to next one
    {
        printf("%d", **arr1); // ** is the content and * is the address i think, right?
        *arr1++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What output did you get?  What did you expect?  What debugging have you done so far?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Well, I guess it's closer.  You know, if you just *write* the code with better formatting, that will help you to avoid bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `merge()` code expects the array to be terminated by zero. The calling code is not doing it, so the behavior is unspecified (I got segfault when I tried your code).

The other issue is that you should put parentheses around `*arr1`:

```
(*arr1)++;
```

When I run your code with this modification and enter zero for the last element, your code runs fine.

Comment: Right, so i would like to check if there is anything valid in that pointer value, should should i fill in the while statement??

Comment: @qwrqwr One way to do it would be to allocate an extra element in `malloc`, and put zero in *after* the loop. Of course this prevents users from entering zero; if this is a problem, either use another number as your "guard", or pass in your `size1` to `merge` as a second parameter.

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to check if that element is valid without using a extra size parameter??

Comment: @qwrqwr yes, this is correct.

Comment: :( so i guess i will have to somehow extend the "array" and add an zero after it. Thanks for help bro!